# Use the OpenLandMaps API to get cordinates of a data range

Tags: python, gis, geospatial

I am using openlandmaps API and I am getting a value for a specific query. I want to use this value to create a range then query OpenLandMaps to get points (ideally coordinates ) that have this values for the corresponding regex.

For example I am using

```
ldg_organic.carbon.stock_msa.kgm2_td_250m_b0..30cm_2001..2015_v0.2.tif
```

and I got the land degradation index for organic carbon stock for a point (2.1245, 70.3212) as 10. I want to get all the order  coordinates in OpenLandMaps that have the value of organic carbon stock within the range of 5 and 15.

I will further process this coordinates for different purposes.
Is there a way to achieve this in Python?